# Setting the header tag (<h3>) using style tag or programmatically through Java

Tags: java, html, css, wicket

I have a `<div>` tag with one wicket id and a class for CSS, It contains the heading for the table. inside that div, I am defining some table columns.

```
<div wicket:id="Test" class="TestClass">
    ----------
    ----------
    Table columns
    ----------
</div>
```

In the HTML file Nowhere the header tags `(<h1>, <h2>...)` are mentioned But in the browser, it is showing `<h3>` tag for all the fields (header and columns). No clue from where it is taking the header tags.

Is it because of the class attribute? and

As I searched, we can only set h3 tag using `<h3>` in the HTML page.
Is there any way we can set the header tag using the CSS class, similar to

```
.TestClass{
color: red;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat In HTML there is no header tag mentioned. But in the browser dev tools, it is showing `<h3>` tag for all the fields. and I need to change only header to `<h2>`.

Comment: Please show us the real Java and HTML code. Maybe some 3rd party library generates the h3

Comment: To answer your question: no, there is no way, using CSS alone, to change an element into another element or to create new element nodes. What CSS ___can___ do however, is make an element _look like_ another element. `display:block; font-size:117%; font-weight:700; margin:.85em 0`.

Comment: Are you using some `wicket` component like a `DefaultDataTable` with toolbars?. Please add some code